# klee on c++14 programs

Tags: c++, llvm, c++14, klee

As I have understood, I can not use `klee` on programs in `C++14`, as
`llvm-3.4` does not support it.

However, I would like to know if there is any way, trick, experimental
version, etc, which would allow me use klee on c++14 programs.

Answer (score 0):

klee is effectively dead, so I doubt it will be updated to something newer than LLVM 3.4 unless there will be someone who will start to maintain it.

Comment: Last release is from 31 March 2016, and there is Pull request for LLVM 3.8 support...

Comment: @Jarod42, oh really, where? http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/klee/ shows the last commit was 21 months ago with just "URL" fix.

Comment: @Jarod42 (or someone else) do you know if it exists another environment that computes inputs for traversing all the execution paths of a given function?